# Why is my expression not a quantified system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

[image]

Who can help me to understand why my code is wrong? It is giving me a message saying "is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities"?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead  of (or in addition to) images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Perhaps you meant `D[equation, {{x, y}}]`?  (Double `{{}}`)

Comment: Ponder on the output of `\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x, y\)]\({x^2 == 0}\)\)`. (Paste it in and it'll become clear what that is.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's simply things way down. Consider,

```
eq = D[{a x/ y + b y/x == 0, {x, y}}]
```

> `{(a*x)/y + (b*y)/x == 0, {x, y}}`

This gives the same error message as you are getting but with a much simpler form.

```
Solve[eq, {x, y}]
```

> Solve::naqs: (a*x)/y + (b*y)/x == 0 && {x, y} is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. >>
>
> `Solve[(a*x)/y + (b*y)/x == 0, {x, y}}, {x, y}]`

This is clear -- `{x, y}` is not an equation nor an inequality.

What will work here is to write

```
eq = D[a x /y + b y/x, x, y] == 0
```

> `-(b/x^2) - a/y^2 == 0`

which is a legitimate equation.